# Updating JSX From Array in Async Function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

I am looking to display nft names from an api.  I can get them to console log, but am struggling on figuring out how to display the data on screen. I tried useState but it somehow ended up in an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core";
import { Alchemy, Network } from "alchemy-sdk";

const Account = () => {
    const [nftRet, setNft] = useState(['']);

    const {account} = useEthers()
    const config = {
        apiKey: "VtnN1OT-RIJ6NtmzCvMg7fUTKPpXrSrq",
        network: Network.MATIC_MUMBAI    
      };
    const alchemy = new Alchemy(config) 
    const walletAddress = `${account}`;
    const tnsContractAddress = '0xAc11134935a810cD4091e3cE62766faB7CC91e49'  // replace with tns contract address
    const main = async () => {
        const nfts = await alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner(walletAddress, {
            contractAddresses: [tnsContractAddress],
        });
    // Parse output
    const numNfts = nfts["totalCount"];
    const nftList = nfts["ownedNfts"];
    console.log(`Total NFTs owned by ${account}: ${numNfts} \n`);
   
    let i = 1;

    for (let nft of nftList) {
        console.log(`${i}. ${nft.title}`);
        i++;
    }

    }
    const runMain = async () => {
        try {
          await main();
          process.exit?.(0);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          process.exit?.(1);
        }
      };
      
    runMain();


    return (
    <><p
            style={{ width: 600, position: "absolute", marginTop: 400, marginLeft: 135, verticalAlign: "middle", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            Account: {account}</p>
            <p style={{ width: 600, position: "absolute", marginTop: 500, marginLeft: 135, verticalAlign: "middle", justifyContent: "center" }}>

                NFTs: {main} // Trying to print here
            </p></>

    )
}
export default Account;
```

My thought was to set the value of a global array in the for loop to the nft.title. Then display that array in the jsx, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the useEffect hook when doing api calls. You ended up with infine loop because your api call run on every rerender since it is directly called in your component. Take a look at useEffect [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect). And pay attention to your dependencies array. You should let it empty so the api is called when component first render.

What is happening in your code is the following. callApi->setState->rerender. On rerender api is called again, state is setted again, react see a change, it rerenders => infinite loop.

If you wrap your api call in:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 const result = myApiCall();
 setMyState(result);
}, []); //Notice the empty array here.
```

on subsequent rerenders it will not be called again. Since there is no dependency listed in the dependency array that have changed.

Comment: @MaresStefan so i have an await in my api call line inside an async func and its not liking it.  Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I assume the useEffect doesn't let you pass an async callback. You could extract that in a sepparate function and then use it in your useEffect callback.